# PyTorch: Train the same model with different data sets in parallel

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am trying to do domain decomposition (DD) on a Physics-Informed Neural Network (PINN) to solve some differential equations.

I have a single model that I train however I want to train this model on 2 different data sets say one on the left half of my domain and one on the right half, and I want to do this in parallel.

I am currently running the code on my PC with a single GPU but will be moving it to a supercomputer with multiple GPUs. I don't have access to using multiple GPUs just yet so I can't exactly test what will work and what won't but I have an idea I will need to add/change a couple things in my code such as

```
PINN = NN(layers_pinn, xcos_x2cos2_term)
PINN = nn.DataParallel(PINN)
PINN.to(device)
```

After I split up my data how would I train each model on the separated data maybe like

```
split = [split_data1, split_data2]
for data in split
    input = data.to(device)
    output = pinn_train(input) # I have a training function/loop outside of my actual model
```

Would this work, is there something I should add or get rid of, ...?

Here is all the code I am using and my current output

output:

```
Current Device: cuda
Current Device Name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER
Epoch: 0 | Loss: 2.202277183532715
Epoch: 10000 | loss: 1.3260161722428165e-05
Epoch: 20000 | loss: 2.416572442598408e-06
Epoch: 30000 | loss: 1.8506638070903136e-06
Epoch: 40000 | loss: 1.667359242674138e-06
```

Main code:

```
from data import create_residual_data, create_ICBC_data
from train import pinn_train
from model import NN

import numpy as np
import torch

np.random.seed(1234)

torch.manual_seed(1234)
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

print(f'Current Device: {device}')
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print(f'Current Device Name: {torch.cuda.get_device_name()}')
    
Xi, Xf         = -1.0, 1.0
Ti, Tf         =  0.0, 1.0
Nc, N_test     =  100, 40
BC_pts, IC_pts =  100, 100

residual_data = create_residual_data(Xi, Xf, Ti, Tf, Nc, N_test)
xt_resid      = residual_data[0].to(device)
f_hat         = residual_data[1].to(device)
xt_test       = residual_data[2].to(device)

def xcos_x2cos2(x_resid, t_resid):
    return x_resid*torch.cos(t_resid) - (x_resid**2)*(torch.cos(t_resid)**2)

ICBC_data = create_ICBC_data(Xi, Xf, Ti, Tf, BC_pts, IC_pts)
IC_xt     = ICBC_data[0].to(device)
IC_u1     = ICBC_data[1].to(device)
IC_u2     = ICBC_data[2].to(device)
BC_xt     = ICBC_data[3].to(device)
BC_u      = ICBC_data[4].to(device)    
xcos_x2cos2_term = xcos_x2cos2(xt_resid[:,0][:,None],   xt_resid[:,1][:,None]).to(device)

layers_pinn = np.array([2, 40, 40, 1])
lr_pinn     = 0.0005
epochs_pinn = 40000

PINN = NN(layers_pinn, xcos_x2cos2_term).to(device)

pinn_losses = pinn_train(PINN, xt_resid, IC_xt, IC_u1, IC_u2, 
                         BC_xt, BC_u, f_hat, epochs_pinn, lr_pinn)
```

training loop:

```
import torch

def pinn_train(PINN, xt_resid, IC_xt, IC_u1, IC_u2, BC_xt, BC_u, 
          f_hat, epochs_pinn, lr_pinn):
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(PINN.parameters(), lr=lr_pinn)
    
    for i in range(1, epochs_pinn+1):
        loss_values = PINN.loss(xt_resid, f_hat, IC_xt, IC_u1, IC_u2, BC_xt, BC_u) 
        if (i == 1):
            print(f"Epoch: 0 | Loss: {loss_values.item()}")
    
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_values.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        if (i % 5000 == 0) or (i == epochs_pinn):
            print(f'Epoch: {i} | loss: {loss_values.item()}')
```

data:

```
from torch import cos, linspace, meshgrid, hstack, zeros, vstack

def initial_u(x, t=0):
    return x

def initial_dudt(x, t=0):
    return 0*x

def boundary_min(t, x=-1):
    return -cos(t)

def boundary_max(t, x=1):
    return cos(t)

def create_ICBC_data(Xi, Xf, Ti, Tf, BC_pts, IC_pts):
    ##########################################################
    x_BC = linspace(Xi, Xf, BC_pts)
    t_BC = linspace(Ti, Tf, BC_pts)
    X_BC, T_BC = meshgrid(x_BC, t_BC, indexing='ij')
    
    x_IC = linspace(Xi, Xf, IC_pts)
    t_IC = linspace(Ti, Ti, IC_pts)
    X_IC, T_IC = meshgrid(x_IC, t_IC, indexing='ij')
    ##########################################################
    IC_x  = X_IC[:,0][:,None]
    IC_t  = zeros(IC_x.shape[0], 1)
    IC_u1 = initial_u(IC_x)     
    IC_u2 = initial_dudt(IC_x) 
    IC    = hstack((IC_x, IC_t))
    ##########################################################
    BC_bottom_x = X_BC[0,:][:,None] 
    BC_bottom_t = T_BC[0,:][:,None] 
    BC_bottom_u = boundary_min(BC_bottom_t)
    BC_bottom   = hstack((BC_bottom_x, BC_bottom_t)) 
    ##########################################################
    BC_top_x = X_BC[-1,:][:,None] 
    BC_top_t = T_BC[-1,:][:,None] 
    BC_top_u = boundary_max(BC_top_t)
    BC_top   = hstack((BC_top_x, BC_top_t))
    ##########################################################
    xt_train_BC = vstack((BC_top, BC_bottom))
    u_train_BC  = vstack((BC_top_u, BC_bottom_u))
    ##########################################################
    return IC, IC_u1, IC_u2, xt_train_BC, u_train_BC  

def create_residual_data(Xi, Xf, Ti, Tf, Nc, N_test):
    ##########################################################
    x_resid = linspace(Xi, Xf, Nc)
    t_resid = linspace(Ti, Tf, Nc)
    
    XX_resid, TT_resid = meshgrid((x_resid, t_resid), indexing='ij')
    
    X_resid = XX_resid.transpose(1,0).flatten()[:,None]
    T_resid = TT_resid.transpose(1,0).flatten()[:,None]
    
    xt_resid    = hstack((X_resid, T_resid))
    f_hat_train = zeros((xt_resid.shape[0], 1))
    ##########################################################
    x_test = linspace(Xi, Xf, N_test)
    t_test = linspace(Ti, Tf, N_test)
    
    XX_test, TT_test = meshgrid((x_test, t_test), indexing='ij')
    
    X_test = XX_test.transpose(1,0).flatten()[:,None]
    T_test = TT_test.transpose(1,0).flatten()[:,None]
    
    xt_test    = hstack((X_test, T_test))
    ##########################################################
    return xt_resid, f_hat_train, xt_test
```

model:

```
import torch
from torch import cos
import torch.autograd as autograd
import torch.nn as nn
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

torch.manual_seed(1234)

class custom_cos(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return cos(x)
   
class NN(nn.Module):    
    def __init__(self, layers, xcos_x2cos2_term):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.alpha = -1; self.beta = 0; self.gamma = 1

        self.layers = layers
        self.loss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i+1]) for i in 
                                      range(len(layers)-1)])
        
        self.xcos_x2cos2_term = xcos_x2cos2_term
        
        for i in range(len(layers)-1):
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linears[i].weight.data, gain=1)
            nn.init.zeros_(self.linears[i].bias.data)  
    
        self.activation = custom_cos()
    
    def forward(self, x):       
        a = x.float()
        for i in range(0, len(self.layers)-2):
            z = self.linears[i](a)
            a = self.activation(z)
        a = self.linears[-1](a)
        return a
    
    def lossR(self, xt_residual, f_hat):
        """Residual loss function"""
        g = xt_residual.clone().requires_grad_()

        u = self.forward(g)
        u_xt = autograd.grad(u, g, torch.ones(g.shape[0], 1).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]
        u_xx_tt = autograd.grad(u_xt, g, torch.ones(g.shape).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]
    
        u_xx = u_xx_tt[:,0][:,None]
        u_tt = u_xx_tt[:,1] [:,None]
        
        f1 = torch.add(u_tt, self.alpha*u_xx)
        f2 = torch.add(self.beta*u, self.gamma*torch.square(u))
        f = torch.add(torch.add(f1, f2), self.xcos_x2cos2_term)
        
        return self.loss_function(f, f_hat)
    
    def lossIC1BC(self, ICBC_xt, ICBC_u):
        """First initial and both boundary condition loss function"""
        loss_ICBC = self.loss_function(self.forward(ICBC_xt), ICBC_u)
        return loss_ICBC
    
    def lossIC2(self, IC_xt, IC_u2):
        """Second initial condition loss function"""
        g = IC_xt.clone().requires_grad_()
        
        u = self.forward(g)
        u_xt = autograd.grad(u, g, torch.ones(g.shape[0], 1).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]
        u_t = u_xt[:,1][:,None]
        
        return self.loss_function(u_t, IC_u2)

    def loss(self, xt_residual, f_hat, IC_xt, IC_u1, IC_u2, BC_xt, BC_u):
        loss_R   = self.lossR(xt_residual, f_hat)
        loss_IC1 = self.lossIC1BC(IC_xt, IC_u1)
        loss_IC2 = self.lossIC2(IC_xt, IC_u2)
        loss_BC  = self.lossIC1BC(BC_xt, BC_u)
                
        return loss_R + loss_IC1 + loss_IC2 + loss_BC
```

The actual PDE can be seen here: https://deepxde.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demos/pinn_forward/klein.gordon.html